# Center text within div

Tags: css, html, alignment

I have a progress box that I would like to align the 'heading' in the center.

The box itself I think is fairly straight forward:

```
<div id="progressContainer" class="progressBox">
<div id="pbar" class="ui-progressbar ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" role="progressbar" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" aria-valuenow="1">
<div class="progress-label">
    Step 1 of 4
</div>
<div class="ui-progressbar-value ui-widget-header ui-corner-left" style="width: 1%;">
</div>
</div>
    <ul id="progress">
       <li id="step0" class="current">Details <span></span></li>
       <li id="step1">Details<span></span></li>
       <li id="step2">Details<span></span></li>
       <li id="step3">Details<span></span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The css for the heading:

```
.progress-label {
color: #000;
position: absolute;
top: 2px;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

adding `text-align:center;` or `margin:0 auto;` etc do not seem to work.
Adding `Left:33%;`does make it roughly centered but not for all screen widths.

Could someone point out what I am doing wrong?

[jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/e7CEK/)

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `position: absolute; top: 2px;` to make it center.

[A working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jP5tt/)

Comment: You're welcome. Just need to learn more about CSS position attribute and you can fix related issues with aligning elements: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp

Answer (score 1):

Why is that div absolutely positioned? Just remove `position: absolute;` and then `text-align: center;` will work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove position:absolute

```
.progress-label {
 color: #444;
 top: 2px;
 font-weight: bold;
 text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this style in the main div

```
.progressBox {
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -50px;    
 }
```

Working demo http://jsfiddle.net/e7CEK/9/